# passing the data in $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I am getting the data from my web service and storing the same data into my `scope` variable like

```
then(function (Tlist) {
                    $scope.Tlist=Tlist.data;
                })
```

and displaying the same data into table, now in my table i am selecting the row by checkbox like

```
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkall" ng-model="Ldata.checked" data-ng-click="calculateTotal(Ldata)" />
                    </td>
```

and in my `"calculateTotal(Ldata)"` function i want to store the value of `(Ldata.amount)` into another `$scope` variable

this is how my condition inside the function looks

```
        if (Ldata.checked) {
            $scope.total += Number(Ldata.amount);
            console.log(Ldata.amount);
            console.log(Number($scope.total));
        }
```

but on

```
console.log(Number($scope.total));
```

line my result is coming as `NaN` but on this line and on `console.log(Ldata.amount);` this line my result is coming as `1400` so i am not able to understand why i am unable to pass data from one variable to another

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking here.  what does the first code snippet have to do with the rest of the question?  What is in `$scope.total` when you start here?  What does `console.log($scope.total);` output?  It seems like `$scope.total` isn't a legal number...

Comment: The title of the question is misleading, since this doesn't really appear to have anything at all to do with "passing the data in $scope variable".....

Comment: please edit your question and be more specific so that we can go through solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive `NaN` probably because the $scope.total is `undefined`. If you really want to use `+=` operator you need to know two things:

- `a += b` is a shortcut of `a = a + b`
- any math operation on number value and `undefined` will return `NaN` value

Just set the initial value to `$scope.total` - for example at the beginning of your controller definition set `$scope.total = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **`Number`** use **`parseInt`**

```
 console.log(parseInt($scope.total));
```